# unix line endings versus windows line endings

Tags: unix

The below is verification of the line endings.  Just curious what is the `I`?  I know the `M` causes issues. Thank you :).

```
cmccabe@DTV-A5211QLM:~/Desktop/bed$ head -10 xgen_targets_unix.bed | cat -et
chr1^I955543^I955763^IAGRN-6|pr=2|gc=75^I0^I+$
chr1^I957571^I957852^IAGRN-7|pr=3|gc=61.2^I0^I+$
```

compared to windows line endings

```
cmccabe@DTV-A5211QLM:~/Desktop/bed$ head -10 xgen_targets.bed | cat -et
chr1^I955543^I955763^IAGRN-6|pr=2|gc=75^I0^I+^M$
chr1^I957571^I957852^IAGRN-7|pr=3|gc=61.2^I0^I+^M$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

^M is char(13) aka \r and ^J is char(10) aka \n.

You tend not to see ^J listed as ^J though. For \r\n it's ^M^J   Some editors might let you enter in ^M and/or ^J with control.

And given the ascii table, and that i is the 9th letter, no doubt ^I is char(9) - tab

You can see the characters clearly with xxd -p, but we'll try your command as well cat -et

We see that when cat -et shows $, it means \n  So ^M$ is \r\n

```
C:\>echo abc>a.a

C:\>cat a.a | xxd -p
6162630d0a

C:\>cat a.a -et
abc^M$

C:\>dos2unix a.a
Dos2Unix: Processing file a.a ...

C:\>cat a.a -et
abc$

C:\>
```